# ParseTree traversal in antlr4

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4

I am using [antlr4 c++](https://soft-gems.net/the-antlr4-c-target-is-here/).
I have a `ParseTree` and I am trying to recreate the tree structure.
To to this I am using a Visitor `my_Visitor` and my own node object(s).

My problem is that `visitChildren(tree::RuleNode*)` calls the visit functions of all children, so I am losing the information when one child tree is traversed and the next child tree is visited.

Assume a tree like this:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

When I call `visitChildren(A)` (using overloaded `visitExpression(ExpressionContext*)` functions for B and C), I can extract the information that the visit sequence is A,B,C.

This sequence could also result from:

```
A
|
B
|
C
```

To recreate the tree I think I would need something like

```
antlrcpp::Any my_Visitor::my_visitChildren(tree::RuleNode* A){
    for(int i=0;i<A->children.size();i++){
        //create a new node in my own tree representation as child of A
        visit(A->children[i]);
    }
}
```

and call `my_visitChildren` in my overloaded `visitExpression` functions.

The problem here is that `A->children[i]` is a `Tree` and `visit(.)` needs a `ParseTree`.

Can I somehow create a `ParseTree` from `children[i]` or is there a better approach to do this?

I am also thinking about using a map from `tree->parent` to my objects and just attach my new node there, but this is not optimal if I wanted to omit some nodes (e.g. for an AST).

Comment: Seems like you need to use listeners not visitors.

Comment: Do I use `exitEveryRule(.)` to get the information that I left a child? Is that what you are suggesting? Because that seems to make sense.. (I am just asking to make sure) :)

Comment: There is a class for that called ParseTreeAnnotator or something. It is like a stack.. Check the example in the book definitive antlr4 reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differentiation between a `ParseTree` and a `Tree` is purely artificial and in fact of no real use. The children of a tree node are in fact all `ParseTree` instances. There are a few tree classes that are never used in the runtime, except for building the base classes of `ParseTree`. Hence later on I have removed `Tree`, `SyntaxTree` and `RuleNode` and put all that together into the ParseTree class.

To answer your question: you can safely cast the child nodes to `ParseTree` for your tree walk.